# Need to embed Excel worksheet in .NET application

Tags: .net, excel

I need to embed an Excel workbook/worksheet in a .NET WinForms application.
So far, i have found only one way of doing it - by adding a Web Browser control to the application and navigating to an Excel file using this control. This is a very cumbersome solution.
Is there an easier way of doing it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) comes with an Excel compatible Windows Forms spreadsheet control which you can simply drag to your form. It includes a Workbook Designer which allows you to edit workbooks right in Visual Studio or load Excel workbooks from disk, and also includes a comprehensive API which is similar to Excel (except that it is .NET friendly).

You can [learn more](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/windowsforms.aspx) and try the [free evaluation](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) for yourself if this might work for you.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC